# convert list of hex string to hex list

Tags: dart

I would need to convert this list of Strings:

```
[00, 02, F0, 12, 04, 00, 00, 05, 03, 01]
```

into

```
[0x00, 0x02, 0xF0, 0x12, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x03, 0x01]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused about what you really want but here is an example of some operations you can do:

```
void main() {
  // List of strings
  final input = ['00', '02', 'F0', '12', '04', '00', '00', '05', '03', '01'];

  // List of ints
  final output = input.map((e) => int.parse(e, radix: 16)).toList();

  // Print list of ints in radix 10
  print(output); // [0, 2, 240, 18, 4, 0, 0, 5, 3, 1]

  // Print list of ints as hex strings
  print(output.map(toHexString).toList());
  // [0x00, 0x02, 0xf0, 0x12, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x03, 0x01]
}

String toHexString(int number) =>
    '0x${number.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}';
```

And if your strings are actually beginning with "0x" you can do this:

```
void main() {
  // List of strings
  final input = ['0x00', '0x02', '0xF0', '0x12', '0x04', '0x00', '0x00', '0x05', '0x03', '0x01'];

  // List of ints
  final output = input.map((e) => int.parse(e.replaceFirst('0x', ''), radix: 16)).toList();

  // Print list of ints in radix 10
  print(output); // [0, 2, 240, 18, 4, 0, 0, 5, 3, 1]

  // Print list of ints as hex strings
  print(output.map(toHexString).toList());
  // [0x00, 0x02, 0xf0, 0x12, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x03, 0x01]
}

String toHexString(int number) =>
    '0x${number.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}';
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I need to convert the String list to int list with `0x??`. If I parse with `int.parse(0x05)`, it returns `5`, but I need `0x05.

Comment: Is 0x part of each string? If so, please update your example.

Comment: Also, please make your example clear about precise types. You latest comment "convert the String list to int list with 0x??" does not really make much sense since integers in Dart are numbers. You can convert this numbers to Strings which has the format "0x??" but the numbers themselves is still just numbers which a default toString which output the number in radix 10.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I need improve my english :) Finally I have used your first suggestion in your last comment (without 0x??) and works very well. Thanks @julemand101

Answer (score 2):

This function may help you:

- `toHex()` method can convert unit8stringlist to hex list
- `toUnitList()` method can convert hex list to unit8stringlist

```dart
static toHex(Uint8List bArr) {
    int length;
    if (bArr == null || (length = bArr.length) <= 0) {
      return "";
    }
    Uint8List cArr = new Uint8List(length << 1);
    int i = 0;
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < length; i2++) {
      int i3 = i + 1;
      var cArr2 = [
        '0',
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5',
        '6',
        '7',
        '8',
        '9',
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
        'D',
        'E',
        'F'
      ];

      var index = (bArr[i2] >> 4) & 15;
      cArr[i] = cArr2[index].codeUnitAt(0);
      i = i3 + 1;
      cArr[i3] = cArr2[bArr[i2] & 15].codeUnitAt(0);
    }
    return new String.fromCharCodes(cArr);
  }

  static hex(int c) {
    if (c >= '0'.codeUnitAt(0) && c <= '9'.codeUnitAt(0)) {
      return c - '0'.codeUnitAt(0);
    }
    if (c >= 'A'.codeUnitAt(0) && c <= 'F'.codeUnitAt(0)) {
      return (c - 'A'.codeUnitAt(0)) + 10;
    }
  }

  static toUnitList(String str) {
    int length = str.length;
    if (length % 2 != 0) {
      str = "0" + str;
      length++;
    }
    List<int> s = str.toUpperCase().codeUnits;
    Uint8List bArr = Uint8List(length >> 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
      bArr[i >> 1] = ((hex(s[i]) << 4) | hex(s[i + 1]));
    }
    return bArr;
  }
```

Comment: You do know that [`int.parse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/int/parse.html) does take an optional parameter named `radix` which could properly simplify your solution quite a bit?

Comment: @dyy.alex I'm trying to use your code, but not luck. I need  to convert a String list to a list of int in format **0x??**  to send it to bluetooth device. `await characteristicsTX.write(output, withoutResponse: false);`. Can you show me an example for convert a String list to int list?

Comment: try post-deal.....add "0x" to each string by your self. Just another for-loop

Comment: This worked pretty well, but in order to convert from string to hex you need to remove the 0x